# I can't clear at all, If I use more than 3 statements of for loop in js, whether I use semicolon(;) or coma(,)

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Like this

```
(i = 0 len = cars.length text = "" i < len i++)
```

replace of this one-

```
(i = 0; i < len; i++)
```

Is javascript have specific rule where I should to use comma or semicolon?

Comment: What is question are you using `,` in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us consider the following `for` loop

```
for(let i=0,len=val.length;i<val;i++){}
```

In the above loop, the variable length and i is declared inside the loop. In that case, it is necessary to use comma separation.

Let us consider the following `for` loop

```
let len = val.length;
for(let i=0;i<len;i++){}
```

In the above case, the variable len is declared before the loop itself and hence just a semicolon(;) separator is sufficient.